# Related memberships not being added for a newly created related contact

Tags: drupal

For one of our sites running drupal Drupal 7.80 and CiviCRM 5.33.5 has organisation based fixed memberships with relationship type set to employer of for the related memberships.

[image]

We have noticed that when a new employee is added to one of these organisations, we have to manually create the related membership by clicking on a CREATE button.

We want the related membership to be created automatically without the need to manually click the create button. Is there an option that we've missed out somewhere to help make this happen?

Comment: The related memberships should be automatically created.  I'd start by upgrading - you should be on at least 5.35.2 (the last security release).  Can you reproduce this on the demo site at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/?

Answer (score -1):

An organizational membership sounds like orgs are signing up for the membership in which case the relationship should be 'employee of' I think.

Comment: This is not correct. if the organisation owns the Membership then it should be set to 'employer of' if you want the membership to be inherited by employees.